# Boost Beast "bad version" while handshake and "Operation cancelled" in write

Tags: c++, websocket, boost-asio, boost-beast

I've constructed a socket client and server and using it communicate locally
Building is good, but when running in root privilege(bind() needs root), the socket got bad version while handshake.

for simplicity, the error code came in:
on_handshake()
on_write()

Beast version: 1.70.0

Code:
ClientService.cc

```
// Client Connect to Server
void ClientService::Connect(const std::string &host, unsigned int port) {
    const auto id = (unsigned int)(mpSLAM->GetMap()->mnId);

    mThread = new std::thread([this, host, port, id] {
        auto const text = "Hello, world!";
        info("client {} connect to host {} port {}", id, host, port);

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        boost::asio::io_context ioc;

        work_guard_type workGuard(ioc.get_executor());

        const std::string  specify_local_address = "0.0.0.0";
        unsigned int  specify_local_portnumber = 20000;

        info("In connection: client bind to local endpoint host {} port {}", specify_local_address, specify_local_portnumber);


        // Launch the asynchronous operation, which would call WebSocket.h
        auto session = std::make_shared<WS::Client::session>(ioc, specify_local_address.c_str(), reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(specify_local_portnumber),
                                                             std::bind(&ClientService::OnRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1));


        this->service = session;
        session->run(host.c_str(), reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(port), text);

        // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
        // the socket is closed.
        ioc.run();

    });
}

void ClientService::SendRequest(const Request &req) {
    // serialize and send request
    std::string msg = ORB_SLAM2::toString(req);

    this->service->send(make_shared<std::string>(msg));
}
```

WebSocket.h of client

```
namespace Client {
// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
//    we do not need a resolver since itself initialize a connection
//    tcp::resolver resolver_;
//    websocket::stream <tcp::socket> ws_;
    websocket::stream <beast::tcp_stream> ws_;
//    beast::tcp_stream ws_;
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const std::string>> queue;
    std::string host_;
    std::uint8_t port_;
    std::function<void(const std::string&)> on_message;
    std::string localhost_;
    std::uint8_t localport_;

    //the constructor
public:
    // Resolver and socket require an io_context
    explicit
        session(net::io_context &ioc, char const *localhost, unsigned int *localport, std::function<void(const std::string&)> on_message)
    : ws_(net::make_strand(ioc)), on_message(std::move(on_message))
    {
        localhost_ = localhost;

        std::stringstream str_port_value;
        str_port_value << localport;
        str_port_value >> localport_;

        beast::error_code err;
        
        //Here I've bind the local endpoint
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), err);
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().bind(tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4(localhost_), localport_));

    }


    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
            char const *host,
            unsigned int *port,
            __attribute__((unused)) char const *text) {
        // Save these for later
        host_ = host;
        std::stringstream str_port_value;
        str_port_value << port;
        str_port_value >> port_;

        // dropped the resolver
//        resolver_.async_resolve(
//                host,
//                port,
//                beast::bind_front_handler(
//                        &session::on_resolve,
//                        shared_from_this()));

        //construct a tcp::endpoint using ip::address_v4 and port number
        tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host_.c_str()), port_);

        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));
       
        //here just connect to ep without resolver
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().async_connect(
                ep,
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_connect,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
//    on_connect(beast::error_code ec, tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type ep) {
        on_connect(beast::error_code ec)
        {

        //  get the ep parameter from run() as ep_
        tcp::endpoint ep_(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(host_.c_str()), port_);

        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
        // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
        beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
                websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                        beast::role_type::client));

        // output on screen said making a handshake with server
        std::cout << "Making a handshake with server" << std::endl;
        
        //where possibly go wrong
        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                [](websocket::request_type &req) {
                    req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                            " websocket-client-async");
                }));

        // update the host string. This will provide the value of the
        // host HTTP header during the websocket handshake
        // the guide references: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
        host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep_.port());


        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/",
                            beast::bind_front_handler(
                                    &session::on_handshake,
                                    shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_handshake(beast::error_code ec) {
        //here comes the error code
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());
        net::post(ws_.get_executor(), beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this(), ec, 5));
        std::cout << "Handshake successful." << std::endl;
    }

    void
    on_write(
            beast::error_code ec,
            std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
       
        //another error code
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        queue.erase(queue.begin());

        // send the message if any
        if (!queue.empty()) {
            ws_.async_write(net::buffer(*queue.front()),
                           beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
        }
    }
```

WebSocket.h of server

```
public:
    // Take ownership of the socket
    explicit
    session(tcp::socket &&socket, std::shared_ptr<shared_state> state, std::function<void(std::string)> on_message)
            : ws_(std::move(socket)), state(std::move(state)), on_message(std::move(on_message)) {
    }

    ~session() {
        std::cout << "~session()" << std::endl;
        state->leave(this);
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run() {
        // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
        ws_.set_option(
                websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(
                        beast::role_type::server));

        // Set a decorator to change the Server of the handshake
        ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
                [](websocket::response_type &res) {
                    res.set(http::field::server,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) +
                            " websocket-server-async");
                }));

        // Accept the websocket handshake
        ws_.async_accept(
                beast::bind_front_handler(
                        &session::on_accept,
                        shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
        if (ec)
            return fail(ec, "accept");

        state->join(this);
        // Read a message
        do_read();
    }
```

running log:
[11:07:16][3518][I][RegisterRemote:70] Registering remote client
[11:07:16][3518][I][Register:172] client bind to local endpoint host 0.0.0.0 port 20001
[11:07:16][3518][I][Register:173] client register to host 0.0.0.0 port 10088
1 2330
[11:07:16][3518][I][RegisterRemote:79] Registered client with id: 1 and port: 2330
[11:07:16][3518][I][RegisterRemote:85] Connecting to the data channel
[11:07:16][3518][I][RegisterRemote:89] Connected to the data channel
[11:07:16][3533][I][operator():39] client 1 connect to host 0.0.0.0 port 2330
[11:07:16][3533][I][operator():54] In connection: client bind to local endpoint host 0.0.0.0 port 20000
Making a handshake with server
handshake: bad version
Gtk-Message: 11:07:16.297: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
write: Operation canceled

Before I removed the resolver and modified the code with binding local endpoint, it works good.
But I didn't modify the handshake part.
and cannot see whats going on in debug mode because it straight go into the write operation.
is there any wrong with the code?

or is that I used
 `websocket::stream <beast::tcp_stream> ws_;`
although it is used in original code

any assistance and guidance would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Your code has BIG problems. Mainly around overuse of `new`/`delete` and... brrrr reinterpret_cast (sometimes even spelled as C-style casts). They, specifically, seem like obvious bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many bugs surrounding at least port numbers. You are reinterpreting unsigned numbers as... pointers, which you then convert by writing to a string stream and back, but... into `uint8_t`. No **wonder** you "require root" to do `bind`: the first 1024 ports are privileged.

Beyond, you are doing strange things like

- creating a completely redundant `work_guard`, as you are using a block `io_context::run()` later on to do all work
- ignoring/swallowing `error_code`
- `bind`-ing on a client socket; this is very rare - it might be what you intend, although I don't particularly know why
- `consume()`-ing a buffer that is never even used
- setting `this->service` with a single `session` instance; why is there a thread in the first place, if all it does is run the io context?
- making a strand in your client, whereas you know that by definition the `io_context` is owned by a single thread
- the thread is leaked, but it is not detached
- you have an outbound message queue, yet nothing **ever** call `on_write`, so nothing will ever start writing (`queue` is not used outside of `on_write`)
- you are... posting `on_read` manually, with a fake size of `5`?

Adding a `listener` loosely based on the [same Beast example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp), I made it self-contained to reproduce your message:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a6f6820e12c254d)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <functional>

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#define info(...) fmt::print(__VA_ARGS__)

namespace WS {
    namespace net       = boost::asio;
    namespace beast     = boost::beast;
    namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
    namespace http      = beast::http;
    using boost::system::error_code;
    using net::ip::tcp;

    static inline void fail(error_code ec, std::string_view where) {
        info("{}: {}\n", where, ec.message());
    }

    using Message        = std::string;
    using MessageHandler = std::function<void(Message const&)>;

    namespace Client {
        // Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
        class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
            std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Message const>> queue;
            websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream>        ws_;

            beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
            std::string        host_, localhost_;
            std::uint16_t      port_, localport_;
            MessageHandler     on_message;

          public:
            // Resolver and socket require an io_context
            explicit session(net::io_context& ioc, std::string localhost, uint16_t localport,
                             MessageHandler on_message)
                : ws_(net::make_strand(ioc), tcp::v4())
                , localhost_(std::move(localhost))
                , localport_(localport)
                , on_message(std::move(on_message)) //
            {
                auto& s = get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket();
                s.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
                s.bind(tcp::endpoint(net::ip::make_address_v4(localhost_), localport_));
            }

            // Start the asynchronous operation
            void run(std::string host, uint16_t port, std::string text) {
                boost::ignore_unused(text);
                // Save these for later
                host_ = host;
                port_ = port;

                beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

                // here just connect to ep without resolver
                tcp::endpoint ep(net::ip::address::from_string(host_), port_);
                beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().async_connect(
                    ep, beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_connect, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_connect(beast::error_code ec) {
                auto& ll = beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_);

                //  get the ep parameter from run() as ep_
                tcp::endpoint ep_ = !ec ? ll.socket().local_endpoint(ec) : tcp::endpoint{};

                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, "connect");

                // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
                // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
                ll.expires_never();

                // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
                ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::client));

                // output on screen said making a handshake with server
                info("Making a handshake with server\n");

                // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
                ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator([](websocket::request_type& req) {
                    req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " websocket-client-async");
                }));

                // update the host string. This will provide the value of the
                // host HTTP header during the websocket handshake the guide
                // references: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
                host_ += ':' + std::to_string(ep_.port());

                // Perform the websocket handshake
                ws_.async_handshake(host_, "/",
                                    beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_handshake, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_handshake(beast::error_code ec) {
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, "handshake");

                // buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());
                //  net::post(ws_.get_executor(),
                //  beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this(), ec, 5));
                info("Handshake successful.\n");
            }

            void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

                // another error code
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, "write");

                queue.erase(queue.begin());

                // send the message if any
                if (!queue.empty()) {
                    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(*queue.front()),
                                    beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
                }
            }
        };

        struct ClientService {
            struct SLAM {
                auto GetMap() { return &_map; }
                struct {
                    unsigned mnId = 42;
                } _map;
            };
            std::unique_ptr<SLAM> mpSLAM{new SLAM};
            std::thread*          mThread = nullptr;

            void Connect(std::string const& host, uint16_t port);

          private:
            net::io_context ioc;
            using work_guard_type = net::executor_work_guard<net::io_context::executor_type>;
            std::shared_ptr<Client::session> service;

            void OnRequest(Message const& msg) { info("OnRequest('{}')\n", msg); }
        };

        // Client Connect to Server
        void ClientService::Connect(std::string const& host, uint16_t port) {
            auto const id = static_cast<unsigned>( // friends don't let friends use C-style casts
                mpSLAM->GetMap()->mnId);

            mThread =
                new std::thread([this, host, port, id] {
                    auto const text = "Hello, world!";
                    info("client {} connect to host {} port {}\n", id, host, port);

                    // The io_context is required for all I/O
                    net::io_context ioc;

                    work_guard_type workGuard(ioc.get_executor());

                    std::string specify_local_address    = "0.0.0.0";
                    uint16_t    specify_local_portnumber = 20'000;

                    info("In connection: client bind to local endpoint host {} port {}\n",
                         specify_local_address, specify_local_portnumber);

                    // Launch the asynchronous operation, which would call WebSocket.h
                    auto session = std::make_shared<WS::Client::session>(
                        ioc, specify_local_address, specify_local_portnumber,
                        std::bind(&ClientService::OnRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1));

                    this->service = session;
                    session->run(host, port, text);

                    // Run the I/O service
                    ioc.run();
                });
        }
    } // namespace Client

    namespace Server {
        class session;
        struct shared_state {
            void join(session const*) {}
            void leave(session const*) {}
        };

        class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
            websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
            std::shared_ptr<shared_state>  state;
            MessageHandler                 on_message;

          public:
            session(tcp::socket&& socket, std::shared_ptr<shared_state> state,
                    MessageHandler on_message)
                : ws_(std::move(socket))
                , state(std::move(state))
                , on_message(std::move(on_message)) {}

            ~session() {
                info("!session()\n");
                state->leave(this);
            }

            // Start the asynchronous operation
            void run() {
                ws_.set_option(
                    websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::server));

                ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator([](websocket::response_type& res) {
                    res.set(http::field::server,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " websocket-server-async");
                }));

                // Accept the websocket handshake
                ws_.async_accept(
                    beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, "accept");

                state->join(this);
                // Read a message
                // do_read();
            }
        };

        // after the example from
        // https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp
        class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener> {
            net::io_context& ioc_;
            tcp::acceptor    acceptor_;

          public:
            listener(net::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint endpoint) try : ioc_(ioc), acceptor_(ioc) {
                acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
                acceptor_.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
                acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
                acceptor_.listen(net::socket_base::max_listen_connections);
            } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
                fail(se.code(), boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(se.code().location()));
            }

            // Start accepting incoming connections
            void run() { do_accept(); }

          private:
            std::shared_ptr<shared_state> state_ = std::make_shared<shared_state>();

            void do_accept() {
                acceptor_.async_accept(
                    make_strand(ioc_),
                    beast::bind_front_handler(&listener::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
                if (ec) {
                    fail(ec, "accept");
                } else {
                    auto handler = [ep = socket.remote_endpoint()](Message const& msg) {
                        info("From {}: {}\n", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ep), msg);
                    };

                    // Create the session and run it
                    auto conn = std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), state_, handler);
                    conn->run();
                }

                // Accept another connection
                do_accept();
            }
        };
    } // namespace Server
} // namespace WS

int main() {
    using namespace WS;
    net::io_context ioc;

    auto ls = std::make_shared<Server::listener>(ioc, tcp::endpoint{{}, 20'001});
    ls->run();

    Client::ClientService cs;
    cs.Connect("127.0.0.1", 20'000u);

    ioc.run();
}
```

Local output:

[image]

The obvious mistake here is that I'm connecting to `20'000` which is the local-bind port of the client itself! Fixing to `20'001` (or whatever port you ran the server on):

[image]

### BONUS

Addressing some more of the issues mentioned above, and adding actual functionality:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/063efb0eb73bd550)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <deque>

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#define info(...)                    \
    do {                             \
        fmt::print(__VA_ARGS__);     \
        std::fflush(stdout);         \
    } while (0)

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace WS {
    namespace net       = boost::asio;
    namespace beast     = boost::beast;
    namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
    namespace http      = beast::http;
    using boost::system::error_code;
    using beast::bind_front_handler;
    using net::ip::tcp;

    static inline void fail(error_code ec, std::string_view where) {
        info("{}: {}\n", where, ec.message());
    }

    using Message        = std::string;
    using MessageHandler = std::function<void(Message const&)>;

    namespace Client {
        // Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response
        class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
            websocket::stream<beast::tcp_stream> ws_;

            bool                handshake_completed_ = false;
            std::deque<Message> queue_;
            beast::flat_buffer  buffer_;
            std::string         ip_address_, local_addr_;
            std::uint16_t       port_, local_port_;
            MessageHandler      on_message;

          public:
            // Resolver and socket require an io_context
            explicit session(net::any_io_executor ex, std::string localhost, uint16_t localport,
                             MessageHandler on_message)
                : ws_{ex, tcp::v4()} // assumed single-threaded execution context
                , local_addr_{std::move(localhost)}
                , local_port_{localport}
                , on_message{std::move(on_message)} //
            {
                auto& s = get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket();
                s.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
                s.bind({net::ip::make_address_v4(local_addr_), local_port_});
            }

            // Start the asynchronous operation
            void run(std::string ip_address, uint16_t port) {
                // Save these for later
                ip_address_ = ip_address;
                port_       = port;

                beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(30s);

                // host assumed to be resolved address
                get_lowest_layer(ws_).socket().async_connect(
                    {net::ip::address::from_string(ip_address_), port_},
                    bind_front_handler(&session::on_connect, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void stop() {
                post(ws_.get_executor(), [self = shared_from_this()] {
                    info("Closing down websocket\n");
                    get_lowest_layer(self->ws_).cancel();
                    // self->ws_.close("stop");
                });
            }

            void enqueue(std::string msg) {
                post(ws_.get_executor(), [m = std::move(msg), self = shared_from_this()] {
                    self->do_enqueue(std::move(m));
                });
            }

          private:
            void on_connect(beast::error_code ec) {
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

                auto& ll   = get_lowest_layer(ws_);
                // auto local_port = ll.socket().local_endpoint().port();

                //  Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because the
                //  websocket stream has its own timeout system.
                ll.expires_never();

                // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
                ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::client));

                // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
                ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator([](websocket::request_type& req) {
                    req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " websocket-client-async");
                }));

                // update the host string. This will provide the value of the
                // host HTTP header during the websocket handshake the guide
                // references: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
                ip_address_ += ':' + std::to_string(port_); // TODO REVIEW why mutate?

                // output on screen said making a handshake with server
                info("Making a handshake with {}\n", ip_address_);

                // Perform the websocket handshake
                ws_.async_handshake(ip_address_, "/",
                                    bind_front_handler(&session::on_handshake, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_handshake(beast::error_code ec) {
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

                info("Handshake successful.\n");
                ws_.async_read(buffer_, bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));

                handshake_completed_ = true;
                do_write(); // if already queued
            }

            void on_read(error_code ec, size_t n) {
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

                if (on_message)
                    on_message(beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.cdata()).substr(0, n));

                buffer_.consume(n);
                ws_.async_read(buffer_, bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void do_enqueue(Message msg) { // assumed on strand!
                queue_.push_back(std::move(msg));
                if (queue_.size() == 1)
                    do_write();
            }

            void do_write() {
                if (!handshake_completed_ || queue_.empty())
                    return;

                info("{}: Initiating write ({} pending) '{}'\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, queue_.size(),
                     queue_.front());
                ws_.async_write(net::buffer(queue_.front()), // FIFO
                                bind_front_handler(&session::on_write, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_write(beast::error_code ec, size_t) {
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

                queue_.pop_front();
                do_write(); // continue until queue empty
            }
        };

        struct ClientService {
            ~ClientService() {
                if (connection_)
                    connection_->stop();

                // ioc.stop(); // optionally?
                ioc.join();
            }

            void Connect(std::string const& host, uint16_t port) {
                info("client {} connect to host {} port {}\n", mpSLAM->GetMap()->mnId, host, port);

                connection_ = std::make_shared<WS::Client::session>(
                    ioc.get_executor(), //
                    "0.0.0.0", 20'000,
                    std::bind(&ClientService::OnRequest, this, std::placeholders::_1));

                connection_->run(host, port);
            }

            void Send(Message msg) {
                assert(connection_);
                connection_->enqueue(std::move(msg));
            }

          private:
            net::thread_pool ioc{1};
            std::shared_ptr<Client::session> connection_;

            void OnRequest(Message const& msg) {
                info("OnRequest('{}')\n", msg);
                assert(connection_);
            }

            struct SLAM {
                struct Map { unsigned mnId = 42; } _map;
                Map const* GetMap() const { return &_map; }
            };
            std::unique_ptr<SLAM> mpSLAM{new SLAM};
        };
    } // namespace Client

    namespace Server {
        class session;
        struct shared_state {
            void join(session const*) {}
            void leave(session const*) {}
        };

        class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
            websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws_;
            std::shared_ptr<shared_state>  state;
            MessageHandler                 on_message;

          public:
            session(tcp::socket&& socket, std::shared_ptr<shared_state> state,
                    MessageHandler on_message)
                : ws_(std::move(socket))
                , state(std::move(state))
                , on_message(std::move(on_message)) {}

            ~session() {
                info("~session()\n");
                state->leave(this);
            }

            // Start the asynchronous operation
            void run() {
                ws_.set_option(
                    websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::server));

                ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator([](websocket::response_type& res) {
                    res.set(http::field::server,
                            std::string(BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING) + " websocket-server-async");
                }));

                // Accept the websocket handshake
                ws_.async_accept(bind_front_handler(&session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
            }

          private:
            void on_accept(beast::error_code ec) {
                info("{}: {}\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ec.message());
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

                state->join(this);

                do_read();
            }

            beast::flat_buffer buffer_;
            void do_read() {
                ws_.async_read(buffer_, bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_read(error_code ec,  size_t n) {
                info("{}: {}, {}\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ec.message(), n);
                if (ec)
                    return fail(ec, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

                if (on_message)
                    on_message(beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.cdata()).substr(0, n));

                buffer_.consume(n);
                ws_.async_read(buffer_, bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
            }
        };

        // after the example from
        // https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp
        class listener : public std::enable_shared_from_this<listener> {
            net::io_context& ioc_;
            tcp::acceptor    acceptor_;

          public:
            listener(net::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint endpoint) try : ioc_(ioc), acceptor_(ioc) {
                acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
                acceptor_.set_option(net::socket_base::reuse_address(true));
                acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
                acceptor_.listen(net::socket_base::max_listen_connections);
            } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
                fail(se.code(), boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(se.code().location()));
            }

            // Start accepting incoming connections
            void run() { do_accept(); }

          private:
            std::shared_ptr<shared_state> state_ = std::make_shared<shared_state>();

            void do_accept() {
                acceptor_.async_accept(
                    make_strand(ioc_),
                    bind_front_handler(&listener::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
            }

            void on_accept(beast::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket) {
                info("{}: {} from {}\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ec.message(),
                     boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(socket.remote_endpoint()));

                if (ec) {
                    fail(ec, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                } else {
                    auto handler = [ep = socket.remote_endpoint()](Message const& msg) {
                        info("From {}: '{}'\n", boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(ep), msg);
                    };

                    // Create the session and run it
                    auto conn = std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), state_, handler);
                    conn->run();
                }

                // Accept another connection
                do_accept();
            }
        };
    } // namespace Server
} // namespace WS

int main() {
    using namespace WS;
    net::io_context ioc;

    auto ls = std::make_shared<Server::listener>(ioc, tcp::endpoint{{}, 20'001});
    ls->run();

    Client::ClientService cs;
    cs.Connect("127.0.0.1", 20'001u);
    cs.Send("Hello world");
    cs.Send("Bye world");

    ioc.run_for(5s);
}
```

Local test output:

```
client 42 connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 20001
Making a handshake with 127.0.0.1:20001
void WS::Server::listener::on_accept(boost::beast::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket): Success from 127.0.0.1:20000
Handshake successful.
void WS::Server::session::on_accept(boost::beast::error_code): Success
void WS::Client::session::do_write(): Initiating write (2 pending) 'Hello world'
void WS::Server::session::on_read(boost::system::error_code, size_t): Success, 11
From 127.0.0.1:20000: 'Hello world'
void WS::Client::session::do_write(): Initiating write (1 pending) 'Bye world'
void WS::Server::session::on_read(boost::system::error_code, size_t): Success, 9
From 127.0.0.1:20000: 'Bye world'
Closing down websocket
void WS::Client::session::on_read(boost::system::error_code, size_t): Operation canceled
~session()
```

Comment: what you’ve mentioned is really helpful and I correct the code as you mentioned and it works as expected. Actually I'm doing minimal modification on the existing websocket code so that I can bind the local endpoint. As to the problems you have mentioned on_write(), the on_write() are being called by another function on_send() which didn’t showed here. Thanks again for putting such a detail example on binding local endpoint in websocket which I didn’t find on the Internet, I believe this would be a great reference for anyone overcome issues that binding local endpoint to socket.

Comment: I'm not sure - it seems like a very rare requirement, and also quite trivial. I think the only thing I "corrected"was a typo/confusion of ports, which I had made up. Did you notice any other significant difference that was important to the solution?

Comment: yeah I also assume the main problem is port type issue, no much important notice for now, will do some further test to see.